# Bulb failure warning sensor diagnosis

Tags: volvo, warning-light, 850

I have a 1996 Volvo 850 GLT that has an active bulb failure warning. The problem is that it doesn't tell me WHICH bulb.

I have checked all the obvious lights:

- headlights
- high beams
- reverse lights
- brake lights
- front flashers
- rear flashers

All are operating normally. How can I figure out what is triggering the bulb failure sensor?

Comment: Ive had this issue where some connection was loose/intermittent.The computer sees it and throws the code, but of course the light is always on when you go looking for it.

Answer (score 2):

What I ended up doing to solve this problem was to actually pull the light assemblies out so I could see each individual bulb light up.

It turns out that the rear lights actually have TWO bulbs each, and one case, one of the bulbs was out. So, the light still lit, but a bulb was out. With the assembly out, it was obvious.